# Seat selection occurs even when no seats are selected

Tags: java, android

I have been building an app for bus seat reservation. When I selected a seat on the displayed layout corresponding seat no is displayed on given slot and I can move to further steps. If the slot is `null` I can't move to next steps. This is what I have to implement. But now when I select a seat, the seat is getting selected and seat no is displayed on the corresponding slot.

But when I cancel selection, slot become `null` value but I can move to further activity with that null value (That shouldn't happen).

Why is it so??

Source code is given below

**Seatinglayout.java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBindOrColumnIndexOutOfRangeException;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Seatinglayout extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView a1;
    TextView p1;

    ImageView prev,next;

    TextView t1;

    String s1;

    int i =1;

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    String str = "";
    HttpResponse response;
    JSONObject json = null;
    JSONObject jresult = null;
    Context context;

    String source,destination,departure,arrival,duration,buslogo,amount,seattxt,date;

    String URL1 = "http://192.168.1.101/booking/p1.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_seatinglayout);

        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seatinghead1);

        Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),  "font/forte.ttf");

        t1.setTypeface(custom_font);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        source = intent.getExtras().getString("source");
        destination = intent.getExtras().getString("destination");
        departure = intent.getExtras().getString("departure");
        arrival = intent.getExtras().getString("arrival");
        duration = intent.getExtras().getString("duration");
        buslogo = intent.getExtras().getString("buslogo");
        amount = intent.getExtras().getString("amount");
        date = intent.getExtras().getString("date");

        a1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.passenger1);

        p1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passenger1text);

        loadProducts(URL1,a1);

        selectedseat(a1,p1);

        next = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.seatingnext);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);

        prev = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.seatingprev);
        prev.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void loadProducts(String URL, ImageView IMG) {

        String url = URL;
        final ImageView img = IMG;

        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.available);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            //converting the string to json array object
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                            //traversing through all the object
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                //getting product object from json array
                                JSONObject passengers = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                //adding the product to product list
                                if(passengers.getString("id")!= null)
                                {
                                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.reached);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.available);

                                }
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.available);
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void selectedseat(ImageView IMG,TextView TXT)
    {
        final ImageView img = IMG;
        final TextView txt = TXT;
        final TextView seatno;

        seatno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seatingnumber);

        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                img.setSelected(!img.isSelected());
                if(img.isSelected())
                {
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.seat);
                    seatno.setText(txt.getText());
                    seattxt = seatno.getText().toString();
                }
                else
                {
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.available);
                    seatno.setText(null);
                    seattxt = seatno.getText().toString();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void currentSelection()
    {
        try
        {

            if(seattxt == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Seatinglayout.this, "Select a seat to continue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Seatinglayout.this, Passengerinformation.class);
                intent.putExtra("source",source);
                intent.putExtra("destination",destination);
                intent.putExtra("departure",departure);
                intent.putExtra("arrival",arrival);
                intent.putExtra("buslogo",buslogo);
                intent.putExtra("duration",duration);
                intent.putExtra("amount",amount);
                intent.putExtra("seat",seattxt);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(Seatinglayout.this, "Select a seat to continue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        if (view == prev)
        {
             finish();

        }

        if (view == next)
        {
             currentSelection();

        }
    }
}
```

Please check my code. Need some suggestions for the above problem.

Comment: where do you cancel selection?

Comment: @RishabhDhawan How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `selectedseat()` method inside `img click listener` you are updating your `String seattxt` in both the cases. and then in your `currentSelection()` method you are checking if `seattxt` is null otherwise you are starting `Passengerinformation Activity`.

But `seattxt` will not be null as you are updating it in both cases inside `click listener`.

If `img` is not selected you are doing

```
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.available);
seatno.setText(null);
seattxt = seatno.getText().toString();
```

In above code `seattxt` will not be null. It will be `""`, which is not `null`.

`String` `null` check should not be used as `Strings` are `Immutable`.

So in `currentSelection()` method you should use `seattxt` length check

```
if(seattxt.length() == 0) // or if(seattxt.equals("")) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(Seatinglayout.this, "Select a seat to continue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        // start Passengerinformation Activity.
    }
```